# mouse over and mouse out happening at same time

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a home button for my website and using "onmouseover" to change what the button says and I want it to go back to what it said before when the user isn't hovering over the button anymore.

currently I have this:

```
<a href="index.html"><button id="b1" class="b1" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="unHover(this)">{WELCOME}</button></a>
```

and in a separate file I have the JS:

```
function hover(element){

    if(element.alreadyHovered == null) {
        element.alreadyHovered = true;
        console.log("hover");

        let hover = document.querySelector('#b1');
        let anim = [
            { t: "{ }", ms: 200},
            { t: "{K_}", ms: 200 },
            { t: "{KB_}", ms: 200 },
            { t: "{KBO_}", ms: 200 },
            { t: "{KBOA_}", ms: 400 },
            { t: "{KBOAN}", ms: 400 },
        ];
        let stepDenominator = 1;
        if (window.localStorage.stepDenominator)
            stepDenominator = window.localStorage.stepDenominator;
        let i = 0;
        let update = () => {
            let step = anim[i];
            hover.innerText = step.t;
            i++;

            if (i < anim.length)
                setTimeout(update, step.ms / stepDenominator);
            else {
                window.localStorage.stepDenominator = 2;
            }
        }
        update();
    }
}
function unHover(element){
    element.alreadyHovered = null
    console.log("unhover")

    let hover = document.querySelector('#b1');
    let anim = [
        { t: "{W_}", ms: 200 },
        { t: "{WE_}", ms: 200 },
        { t: "{WEL_}", ms: 200 },
        { t: "{WELC_}", ms: 200 },
        { t: "{WELCO_}", ms: 200 },
        { t: "{WELCOM_}", ms: 400 },
        { t: "{WELCOME}", ms: 400 },
    ];
    let stepDenominator = 1;
    if (window.localStorage.stepDenominator)
        stepDenominator = window.localStorage.stepDenominator;
    let i = 0;
    let update = () => {
        let step = anim[i];
        hover.innerText = step.t;
        i++;

        if (i < anim.length)
            setTimeout(update, step.ms / stepDenominator);
        else {
            window.localStorage.stepDenominator = 2;
        }
    }
    update();

}
```

when I use this both functions run at the same time and it doesn't do what I want, please help.

Comment: Add a fixed width to the button. (The problem is that if you're hovering too close to the right edge, changing the text makes the button so small that it's no longer under the mouse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your CSS. There could be a problem that you are hovering a text, and when it changes in size, it cancels the mouse hover.